# flatmap xml sections and bring the parent attributes to children?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

The following code running in SQL Server

```
declare @x xml = '<r x="x">
<s a="1" />
<s a="2" />
<s a="deleted" />
</r>
<r x="y">
<s a="3" />
<s a="4" />
<s a="deleted" />
</r>'

select @x.query('
for $r in /r 
for $s in $r[s/@a != "deleted"] 
let $z := $s (: Need to bring @x from <r> to <s> :)
return
<s>
{$z} (: need to use $z in many places :)
</s>
')
```

returns

```
<s>
  <r x="x">
    <s a="1" />
    <s a="2" />
    <s a="deleted" />
  </r>
</s>
<s>
  <r x="y">
    <s a="3" />
    <s a="4" />
    <s a="deleted" />
  </r>
</s>
```

However, my expected values in `$z` should be

```
    <s a="1" x="x" />
    <s a="2" x="x" />
    <s a="3" x="y" />
    <s a="4" x="y" />
```

I will need to implement

1. flatmap is needed to be applied to the multiple XML sections and

   *Edit:* Can be done using `for $s in $r/s[@a != "deleted"]`
2. Bring the attribute `x` of `<r>` to `<s>` in the final assignment of `$z`.

**Update:**
I will need to do the following which is not supported in SQL Server?

```
let $z := update insert attribute x {$r/@x} $s (: Need to bring @x from <r> to <s> :)
```

Comment: Did you mean `r/s[not(@a="deleted")]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @x xml = '<r x="x">
<s a="1" />
<s a="2" />
<s a="deleted" />
</r>
<r x="y">
<s a="3" />
<s a="4" />
<s a="deleted" />
</r>';

select @x.query('
    <s>
    {
        for $r in /r 
        for $s in $r/s[@a != "deleted"] (: Need to delete <s> which @a is "deleted" :)
        let $z := $s (: Need to bring @x from <r> to <s> :)
        return
        <s a="{$z/@a}" x="{$r/@x}" /> (: Some other code need to use $z:)
    }
    </s>
    ');
```

Output:

```
<s>
  <s a="1" x="x" />
  <s a="2" x="x" />
  <s a="3" x="y" />
  <s a="4" x="y" />
</s>
```

Comment: Can `$z` be added the attribute of `x`? Right now it's `<s>
  <s a="1" />
</s>
<s>
  <s a="2" />
</s>
<s>
  <s a="3" />
</s>
<s>
  <s a="4" />
</s>`

Comment: @dc7a9163d9, I don't know way to add attribute. But I edited answer to get output that you want.

Comment: There is many limitations of xml construction (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xml-construction-xquery) and `FLWOR` (`XQuery [query()]: 'let' is not supported with constructed XML`)

Comment: Yes, I was aware of the limitation of  `'let' is not supported with constructed XML`. However, I found that `let $z := update insert attribute x {$r/@x} $s` not working too.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9, may be you will provide more complex example and desired output to find some workaround?

Comment: Also, I tried to avoid to construct the xml using `<s a="{$z/@a}" x="{$r/@x}" />` because `<s>` has many attributes and not all the nodes have exactly the same number of attributes.